# How to get value of selected in td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table.And I want to get value of selected

```
<tr class="table-info" id="tr1">

    <select class="form-control">
        <option>foobar</option><option>foobar2</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My javascript code

```
var tr_day = document.getElementById("tr" + 1);
var tds_day = tr_day.getElementsByTagName("td");
console.log($("#" + tds_day[1].id).closest('select').find(':selected').html());
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q10wm87h/)

Comment: $( ".form-control option:selected" ).text();

Comment: It just little  part of my code.I have more tr and td's.So i choose tr1's first td. @HarshPatel

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: added jsfiddle demo @HarshPatel

Comment: Why mixing, why native js, when you already using jQuery (which should make this task much easier)? Also, there are some syntax errors...

Comment: You can find my updated answer. changed code according to JSFIddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var tr_day = document.getElementById("tr" + 1);
var tds_day = tr_day.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < tds_day.length; i++) {
  console.log($(tds_day[i]).find(":selected").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="table-info" id="tr1">
    <td>
      <select class="form-control"><option>foobar/option><option>foobar2</option></select>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: @HarshPatel We can call the above code on change event of select input.

Comment: @more Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```js
//You need to write script for all select options.
//This is for only one td
$('.form-control').change(function(){ 
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Gunler</th>
    <Timeslot>
        <th><span class="saatBasl">Saatler</span></th>
            
    <th id="thSample">
        <span class="timeRange">09.00</span>
        <span>     -     </span>
        <span class="timeRange">09.50</span>
    </th>
    <th>
        <span class="timeRange">11.00</span>
        <span>     -     </span>
        <span class="timeRange">11.50</span>
    </th>
    <th>
        <span class="timeRange">12.00</span>
        <span>     -     </span>
        <span class="timeRange">12.50</span>
    </th>
    <th>
        <span class="timeRange">13.00</span>
        <span>     -     </span>
        <span class="timeRange">13.50</span>
    </th>
    <th>
        <span class="timeRange">14.00</span>
        <span>     -     </span>
        <span class="timeRange">14.50</span>
    </th>
    <th>
        <span class="timeRange">15.00</span>
        <span>     -     </span>
        <span class="timeRange">15.50</span>
    </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="Table1">

    <tr class="table-info"  id="tr0">
        <td class="gun">Pazar</td>
     
        <td>

            <select class="form-control">
                <option>foobar</option>
                <option>foobar2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-info"  id="tr1">
        <td class="gun">Pazar</td>
     
        <td>

            <select class="form-control">
                <option>foobar</option>
                <option>foobar2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-info"  id="tr2">
        <td class="gun">Pazar</td>
     
        <td>

            <select class="form-control">
                <option>foobar</option>
                <option>foobar2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-info"  id="tr3">
        <td class="gun">Pazar</td>
     
        <td>

            <select class="form-control">
                <option>foobar</option>
                <option>foobar2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-info"  id="tr4">
        <td class="gun">Pazar</td>
     
        <td>

            <select class="form-control">
                <option>foobar</option>
                <option>foobar2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-info"  id="tr5">
        <td class="gun">Pazar</td>
     
        <td>

            <select class="form-control">
                <option>foobar</option>
                <option>foobar2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-info"  id="tr6">
        <td class="gun">Pazar</td>
     
        <td>

            <select class="form-control">
                <option>foobar</option>
                <option>foobar2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Iterate over the table tr and find the selected options.

```
var optionsList = [];
$.each('table tr',function(){
var currentOption = $(this).find('select option:selected').text();
console.log(currentOption);
optionsList.push(currentOption);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function select(){
  var val = $( ".form-control option:selected" ).text();
  console.log(val)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table>
<tr class="table-info" id="tr1">
  <td>
    <select class="form-control" onchange="select()">
        <option>foobar</option>
        <option>foobar2</option>
        <option>foobar3</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```